# How far in advance should a new author allow pre-orders on Amazon?

Tags: publishing, self-publishing, marketing

I'm in the final stages of packaging the book and would like to start arranging pre-orders to help with the first week "bump". How far in advance should I allow the pre-order option, and is there any specific pitfalls (e.g. discounting) that I should be aware of?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am doing pre-releases for various ebook titles. Ideally you should use the maximum amount of time (3 months for pre-releases). Why?

It often takes reviewers at least a month to review a title. Publications are more likely to assign and run reviews if they know that the review will run fairly close to the official publication date. If you have a shorter pre-release window for contacting reviewers, you are less likely to have anyone review your titles.

I'm speaking only about ebooks here, but I think it applies somewhat to print titles as well.

Answer (score 2):

A month is just about right. That way you can promote it to family, friends, and even your e-mail list, and still build some momentum for it without spending a ton of time pushing a book that no one can read.

Pick a date that you know you can hit.

If you haven't already visited, [this website](http://livewritethrive.com/the-best-way-for-writers-to-use-amazons-preorder-feature/) explains more.